# How to execute the same method continuously and return a value in each execution?

Tags: android, kotlin

What I would like to do is make a method continually run in the background and, on each run, return a value. Also, I have a model and I would like to store the value returned by the method in this model so that I can use this value in another class. Is it possible to do this?

Method:

```
fun generatePair(): Pair<String?, String?> {

    val rand = Random.nextInt(0, 10)
    val num1: String? = "x$rand"
    val num2: String? = "y$rand"

    return Pair(num1, num2)
}
```

Model:

```
  data class PairData(
    val xData: Long,
    val yData: String
  )
```

I want to have the generatePair method running continuously and every time it runs, get a new Pair and store it in data class. After that,  I want to get the Pair in other class. How is posible to do this? Maybe with a service?

Comment: You just need a Thread for the most basic implementation.  The real problem is that you'll hit Android power protections if you background the app, and that doing this you'll eventually run out of memory (how long depends on how big the data structure is and how much heap memory Android will give you on your device).  You generally don't just infinitely generate data with no rate control, but I'm assuming this is a learning project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could save the collection in a singleton arrayList somewhere in your code:

```
object accessibleVariables{
  val pairList = arrayListOf<PairData>()
}
```

Then you could do something like this:

```
fun loopMethod(){
  // Start a new thread to prevent blocking other code
  Thread{
    // You could change this to a variable, to stop the loop when you would like
    while(true){
      accessibleVariables.pairList.add( generatePair() )
    }  

  }.start()      
}
```

Comment: And how can I use the pairList in other class?

Comment: You could then call accassibleVariavles.pairList. The "object" created a singleton class on app startup. All the variables within are accessible for all your classes which implement the module in which the accessibleVariables is created.
You should watch out with the "while(true)" without a Thread.sleep(1000) (wait one second), because using no timeout will flood your memory with PairData objects.

Comment: Hi again, is it posible to access "accessibleVariables" from other project? If I import this project like a library, If I access "accessibleVariables" from other project, I always get null.